# Cannot find a method to read property 'lastname' in a bean of type 'jlab1.beans.Message

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to implement the jsp:getProperty tag. However, web page reported this cannot find property "lastname".

namai.jsp:

```
<form action="/jlab1" method="POST">            
            Vardas
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20px"/>
            Pavardė
            <input type="text" name="lastname" size="20px"/>
            Komentaras
            <input type="text" name="message" size="20px"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Siųsti"/>                   
        </form> 
        <hr>
        <div>
            <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                <jsp:getProperty name="msg" property="name"/>:
                <jsp:getProperty name="msg" property="lastname"/>:
                <jsp:getProperty name="msg" property="msg"/>
            </c:if>
        </div>
```

Controller Servlet Namai.java:

```
        String l_name = "";
        l_name = request.getParameter("name");

        String l_last = "";
        l_last = request.getParameter("lastname");

        String l_msg = "";
        l_msg = request.getParameter("message");

        if (l_name != null && l_last != null && l_msg != null) {
            this.msg.setName(l_name);
            this.msg.setLastname(l_last);
            this.msg.setMsg(l_msg);
            this.msg.setTime(new Date());
}
```

Model class Message.java:

```
    private String name;
    private String lastname;
    private String msg;    
    .....        
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastname;
    }        
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `getLastname()` instead of `getLastName()`. The size of letters matters.

Btw. use your IDE to generate setters / getters. It's fast and more sure way :) Alternatively you can use some library for it, eg. Lombok.

Comment: It's working!!!. Thank you.
And, I would ask you why isn't getLastName() working in Java execution?

Comment: That's how the mechanism works: get the property name, change the first letter to uppercase, add get or is prefix (based on type) and try to find method with this name in your bean. And you didn't have method "getLastname()" for proerty "lastname".

Comment: btw. @LukasGužauskas you can mark your questions as "Solved" by click Accept near my answer :)